# Regex in Power Query errors out when passed a string with double quotes

Tags: javascript, excel, regex, powerquery

I'm using a workaround to get regex to work in an Excel Power Query.  See code below.  It works great except when you pass a string to the regex that contains a double quote anywhere in the string.  And example would be `my "name" is` The error that is raised is `Expression.Error: There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation`.

I think the issue is that when a string with a quote in it is passed to the regex function and then written to the web page, it's no longer valid html code.

Regex function in power query:

```
let
  fx=(txt as text, regex as text)=>
    Web.Page(
        "<script>
            var x="""& txt &""";
            var y=new RegExp('"& regex &"','i');
            var result=x.match(y);
            document.write(result);
        </script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}
in 
  fx
```

I've tried using `replaceAll('"',"'")` to replace the double quote, but I can't get the syntax correct.

Comment: I don't know, but would this work? `var x=""" & Replace(txt, '"', '""') & """; y=/" & regex & "/i;`

Comment: @trincot Thank you for trying.  Unfortunately, it doesn't like the syntax.  The regex should work.  I think once a string with a quote in it is written to the web page it's not valid code.  I have a workaround to use the `Text.Replace()` power query function to first remove the quotes before I pass the string to the regex function.  It works, but it's an extra step that I don't think is necessary if I can figure out the syntax for the regex function.

Comment: I don't know PowerQuery syntax, but in JavaScript you should have no double quotes interrupting the string. They should be escaped. I see that I suggested to replace with `'""'`, but that should be `'\"'` ... but to be done with valid PowerQuery syntax.

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is that power query is passing a string with double quotes as `"my ""name"" is "`. I created a simple function in jsfiddle that does regex. As soon as you pass a string like that, it doesn't work. It works when the string doesn't have the double quotes like this `"my name is"`.  I guess the only way to solve this is to process the string with a power query function before I pass it to the regex function. Thanks so much for your help.